# Postgresql: How to check username and (forgotten) password on a Mac?

Tags: postgresql

Hi I've tried looking around for an answer but don't know how to access my local machine's postgresql username and password. I'm a big noob when it comes to the command line and bash and etc, so please help. Can someone help in helping me find out my username and password for postgres on a Mac?

```
Edmunds-MacBook-Pro:postgres edmundmai$ psql -d db -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to recover a password from PostgreSQL.  However, if you add `local all all trust` to your pg_hba.conf file, it will allow you to log into the cluster without a password from your local machine.  Once you've made the change, restart the server to get it to take effect, and then you can log in and change your password.  Once you're done, be sure to remove this line from your pg_hba.conf and restart the server, as this isn't particularly secure.

Comment: hey scott. I already had local all all trust in my pg_hba.conf file. Could it be that I didn't restart the server? How would I restart the server?

Comment: Essentially, postgres needs to reload this config file after you change it.  To do a reload (instead of a full restart), you should be able to do `sudo su - postgres` to change to the postgres user, and then `pg_ctl reload -D [path to your data directory]`.  This assumes 1. that you have root access, 2. that pg_ctl is in the postgres user's path, 3. That you know the path to your data directory.

Comment: check out this http://tutorialgenius.blogspot.ca/2012/03/restarting-and-managing-services-on-mac.html to see if it helps

Comment: @ScottS I updated the question to include `sudo su - postgres`. I get a password prompt when I type it in and I can't continue from there

Comment: The password prompt you get when you try to do `sudo su - postgres` is for your OS X user (edmundmai).  The password is whatever your password for this user on your machine is.